# How to invoke static methods in android.media.ImageUtils

Tags: android

How to invoke static methods in android.media.ImageUtils?

I encountered errors when using reflection to call it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJMiC.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn2G4.jpg)

However, when I wrote a test class based on android.media.ImageUtils, and accessed it using the same method, I was able to get the correct results.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode